# Check form for null values

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

The variable form contains all form members what I need. It could be, that some form members are null.
So I want to ask if a form member(board) exists before I use it.
I will not do it with try catch, because try is a too general solution for everything. I want to find a smart way to find the null values.

```
DynamicForm form = Form.form().bindFromRequest();

if(form.value("board") != null){
    ...
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: If form have a way to retrive a collection/array of all values, iterate it checking if null. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/data/Form.Field.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm().form().bindFromRequest();
if(form.get("board") == null) {
   // do something
}
```

Notice how my DynamicForm differ from yours.

Answer (score 0):

try catch is not a general solution and should always be there to rethrow or catch the exception. So you should write a try catch, to catch or rethrow potentional exceptions and also you have to check

```
if(null == form) {
    //return/do something
}
```

or

```
if(null != form) {
    if(form.value("board") != null){
        ...
    }
}
```

And also if form contains all form members you should check and not add null values in this collection.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn´t work. --> [NumberFormatException: null]

Comment: If the form board is missing in the form object I will get always a null exception if I try   :  form.value("board"). The same exception when I try the same statement in the if block.